# Kotlin Renaming Generated Getters and Setters

Tags: kotlin, setter, getter

Is there a way to rename the default getters and setters in Kotlin? I have a property named in `snake_case`, but I still want the getters and setters to be named in `camelCase`.

The closest I've gotten is something like

```
private var property_name = Color.BLACK
private set
fun setPropertyName(c: Color) { property_name = c }
fun getPropertyName() = property_name
```

Is there a way to do this without hiding the getters and setters and defining new methods?

Comment: Are you trying to name these using snake case for the benefit of some other system (i.e. JSON serdes?).  Why use the non standard naming for properties?  That context might lead to completely different answers to help you accomplish what you are trying.  (in other words, is this an XY problem http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @JaysonMinard I just like the snake case style when naming my variables, but the project requirements need camel case getters and setters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is described in the section on handling signature clashes: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname

```
val x: Int
    @JvmName("getX_prop")
    get() = 15
```

So `@JvmName("getPropertyName") get` should work.

Comment: This is still pretty tedious, but I guess it still works a lot better

Answer (score 27):

If you just want to change the name and not the functionality, you can also scope the annotation like so:

```
@get:JvmName("getPropertyName")
@set:JvmName("setPropertyName")
var property_name = Color.BLACK
```